# VB.NET Pass values from textbox to datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, textbox

I want to pass values of textboxes to a datagridview using below code.

```
  Private Sub txtDrCr_Leave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtDrCr.Leave

    Dim nR As Integer
    nR = TxtList.Rows.Add()
    TxtList.Item("stsno", nR).Value = nR + 1
    TxtList.Item("stAcctCode", nR).Value = txtAccountCode.Text
    TxtList.Item("stAcctName", nR).Value = txtAccountName.Text
    TxtList.Item("stBranch", nR).Value = txtBranchName.Text
    TxtList.Item("stDescription", nR).Value = txtDescription.Text
    TxtList.Item("stAmount", nR).Value = txtAmount.Text
    TxtList.Item("stDrCR", nR).Value = txtDrCr.Text
    cleartextboxes()
End Sub
```

This code add two lines in the gridview whenever I leave the txtDRCR. I have attached the snapshot as well. Please need kind help. Thanks.

[image: ImageAttached]

Comment: You need to debug your code. If you don't know how, do some research and learn. All developers need to know how and you need to do it before posting a question here. Debugging properly will show you where the two rows are being added and, even if you can't work out how to fix it, at least you can provide us with that relevant information.

Comment: You should discuss on solution instead of writing something which is not related to my question.

Comment: All information is written in the question. Tell me what other information you need.

Comment: My comment is related to your question. You need to do what you can to solve any problem for yourself before posting here. If you haven't debugged then you haven't done that, so you should not be posting here. If you're just starting out then you may not know that, which is why I'm telling you. Now that you know, you can do what you're supposed to. Like I said, every developer needs to be able to debug so there's no better time to learn how than now. We're not here so you don't have to try to fix the problem. We're here to help with the problems you've tried to fix but can't.

Comment: I've told you to debug your code. Have you done so? If not, why not? If so, I told you that it would show where the two rows were being created, so why aren't you telling us that? Debug your code. If you haven't done that then you haven't tried to fix the problem and if you haven't tried to fix the problem then it's too soon to be posting here. Post here when you've tried but were unable to fix the problem.

Comment: I have debugged the code, googled it and tried with many different ways but wasn't able to find the solution That's why cam here.

Comment: When you say that you debugged, did you actually debug, i.e. set a breakpoint, step through the code line by line and examine the values of all relevant variables and other expressions at each step to see exactly where reality differed from your expectation? If not, you haven't debugged the code. If so, why haven't you explained exactly where and how reality differed from your expectation? If it never did then there's something wrong with your expectation.

Comment: I am not familiar with using and setting the breakpoints,

Comment: No one is familiar when they first start out, but everyone needs to learn. Now's the best time for you to do so.

Comment: Found the solution myself. removed the code from TXTDRCR_Leave event. Created new button (btnAdd) and put the code under click event and it worked. Thankyou for suggestion,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code.

```
    Dim nR As Integer =0;
    Dim Row As Integer =0;
    TxtList.Rows.Add()
    Row = TxtList.Rows.Count - 2;

    TxtList("stsno", Row ).Value = nR + 1
    TxtList("stAcctCode", Row ).Value = txtAccountCode.Text
    TxtList("stAcctName", Row ).Value = txtAccountName.Text
    TxtList("stBranch", Row ).Value = txtBranchName.Text
    TxtList("stDescription", Row ).Value = txtDescription.Text
    TxtList("stAmount", Row ).Value = txtAmount.Text
    TxtList("stDrCR", Row ).Value = txtDrCr.Text
    TxtList.Refresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the general concept you want.

```
Private Sub btnAddList_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddList.Click
       Dim i As Integer
       With dgvIssuedBooks
           ' Write to cell (0,0)
           .Rows(i).Cells("CallNumber").Value = txtCallNo2.Text
           .Rows(i).Cells("Title").Value = txtTitle2.Text
           .Rows(i).Cells("AccessionNumber").Value = txtAccess2.Text
           .Rows(i).Cells("Borrower").Value = dgvSearch.Rows(i).Cells("FullName").Value
           .Rows(i).Cells("ID").Value = txtShow.Text

       End With
       txtAccess2.Text = ""
       txtCallNo2.Text = ""
       txtTitle2.Text = ""
   End Sub
```

Check the spelling all all named objects carefully.  Also, just so you know, hitting F11 over and over and over will let you step through the code line by line, so you can see what is actually going on when it runs.